# Nested transactions in Apache Ignite

Tags: transactions, ignite

How to start a transaction without stopping a previously started one?

Any code like this throws exception

```
try (Transaction tx = Ignition.ignite().transactions().txStart()) {
    ...

    try (Transaction tx = Ignition.ignite().transactions().txStart()) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Any Java example or a link would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a new transaction in a separate thread.

For example:

```
Transaction tx1 = Ignition.ignite().transactions().txStart();

new Thread(() -> {
    Transaction tx2 = Ignition.ignite().transactions().txStart();
    ...
    tx2.commit();
}).start();

...

tx1.commit();
```

Comment: Is it a good practice? Have you already tried it?